# How to sum up data into one in dates query?

Tags: sql, oracle, date

```
SELECT 
            NVL(DTM, 'SUM') DTM 
           ,COUNT(PKG_SNO) STUDENT_PKG 
           ,COUNT((CASE WHEN SHAR_YN=1 THEN PKG_SNO END)) SHARED
           ,COUNT((CASE WHEN SHAR_YN=0 THEN PKG_SNO END)) NON_SHARED
  FROM
            /* Dates */
           (SELECT 
                       TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (#startDt#,'YYYY-MM-DD')+LEVEL- 1, 'YYYY.MM.DD') AS DAY
             FROM DUAL
              CONNECT BY TO_DATE(#startDt#, 'YYYY-MM-DD') + LEVEL - 1  <=  TO_DATE(#endDt#, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
           ) DAY LEFT OUTER JOIN



   (
            SELECT 
                      TO_CHAR(RGS_DTM, 'YYYY.MM.DD') DTM
                      ,PKG_SNO
                      ,SHAR_YN
              FROM lrms.v_lrpm_pkg 
            WHERE
                      USE_YNDCD = 1 
                      AND  MNGT_PRDN_YN ='N'
                      AND PARN_PKG_SNO = 0
                      AND TO_CHAR(RGS_DTM, 'YYYY.MM.DD') BETWEEN #startDt# AND #endDt# 
            ) PKG ON DAY.DAY = PKG.DTM 
GROUP BY ROLLUP(DTM)
ORDER BY group by YEAR(yourdae),MONTH(yourdate)
```

Comment: Why *if you pick '20130101' and '20130615', it should sum up every data into one then display it in Jan row* ? is it because the start date is in January ?

Comment: If you pick '20130101' and '20130615', then it should have 6 columns. Every column contains summed up data for each month. Jan should only contain data between Jan 1 ~ Jan 31. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I got your requirement, you need to aggregate some columns for each month. you can use this:

UPDATE 2:

```
SELECT TRUNC(RGS_DTM, 'MM'), COUNT(PKG_SNO) STUDENT_PKG_COUNT, COUNT(SHARED) SHARED_COUNT, COUNT(NON_SHARED) NON_SHARED_COUNT

FROM (SELECT PKG_SNO,
             CASE WHEN SHAR_YN = 1 THEN PKG_SNO END SHARED,
             CASE WHEN SHAR_YN = 0 THEN PKG_SNO ENDNON_SHARED
      FROM lrms.v_lrpm_pkg
      WHERE USE_YNDCD = 1
           AND MNGT_PRDN_YN = 'N'
           AND PARN_PKG_SNO = 0
           AND TO_CHAR(RGS_DTM, 'YYYY.MM.DD') BETWEEN #startDt# AND #endDt#)
GROUP BY TRUNC(RGS_DTM, 'MM')
```

Comment: I just put up the complete query. Hope it helps.

Comment: I already have GROUP BY ROLLUP(DTM). Can I still add TRUNC(datecolumn,'MM')??

Comment: please check my update, I guess you don't need any connect by-rollup.

Comment: dear @user2470075, I just had fogotten the date column of the query in select list. please check update2

Answer (score 0):

group by year and month will do the trick

```
group by YEAR(yourdae),MONTH(yourdate)
```